# BufferedReader readLine() have weird characeters

Tags: java, sockets, console

I have found a issue when I write and read data from sockets, in this time the socket are already open.

The code from server:

```
<pre>ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(2001);
Socket socket = server.accept();
while(true){
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    String readString = br.readLine();
    System.out.println("result:\n"+readString)
}</pre>
```

The test I made from a client

```
<pre>Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 2001);            
Scanner consoleRead= new Scanner(System.in);
consoleRead.useDelimiter("\n");
ObjectOutputStream oo = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
while(true){
    String s = consoleRead.next();
    oo.writeUTF(s+System.lineSeparator());
    oo.flush(); 
}</pre>
```

The first line is read perfectly... But the rest begin with weird characters.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are writing with `ObjectOutputStream` then read with `ObjectInputStream` insted of `InputStreamReader`

`writeUTF()`

*Primitive data write of this String in modified UTF-8 format. Note that there is a significant difference between writing a String into the stream as primitive data or as an Object. A String instance written by writeObject is written into the stream as a String initially. Future writeObject() calls write references to the string into the stream.*

Better is :- Write with `OutputStreamWriter` and read with `InputStreamReader`

For better understanding:- write the same thing in a file with `ObjectOutputStream` and then check what is getting written.

Comment: I think you say OutputStreamWriter on the first case